# How to paste in Wolfram Cloud app on Android?

Tags: import, wolfram-cloud, url

I am using the Wolfram Cloud app on Android and have copied the url of an image that I would like to import. However, I am unable to find a paste menu item or load the paste menu from a long press as you can in other apps.

How do you paste in the Wolfram Cloud app on Android?

[image]

Comment: This is one of many insane bugs and limitations

Answer (score 2):

I could paste text in a ghetto way.

On your virtual Wolfram keyboard press the double upward arrow, top left corner.

Now press something that looks like an equal in a box with two lines connecting to it, top right corner of the virtual keyboard, which should insert a box. I was able to paste into the box using my smartphones default long tap and paste. It should paste the data stored on the clipboard out the box, now you can proceed to delete to box.